# How to make video ads disappear after xx seconds in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am making a video ads, now i can play video from internet, redirect to new url when user tap to the video.

But i dont know how to make Skip button, and stop , disappear my video ads after some seconds

I search google for a long time, but i cant get the solution!

can you give me some advice please?

Comment: Are you creating your own video ads / using a ad provider for this?

Comment: How your video is hosted? Is it a separate activity or a VideoView embedded in a dialog? More technical details, please.

Comment: Hi, i use videoView to show my video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this way:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
             if(mVideoViewer.isPlaying()){
                 mVideoViewer.stopPlayback();
             }

        // Do something
        Log.i(getCallingPackage(), "====== Auto stop ===========");
         } 
    }, 15000);
```

Stop play video after 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try this to stop playing video.

Timer timer=new Timer();

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          if (videoView.isPlaying()) 
{
   videoView.stopPlayback();
}   

        }
    },10000);
```

Comment: Hi, how can i stop it after some second?